Laravel notification is not dispatched
I'm a beginner of Laravel. And for the training of it, I'm learning how to use Laravel following Laravel Bootcamp.
https://bootcamp.laravel.com/blade/notifications-and-events
My code is completely same as this guide though, this program didn't work correctly.
No mail notification is dispatched after chirping.
I guess these two of code might be suspicious.
app/Listeners/SendChirpCreatedNotifications.php
<?php
 
namespace App\Listeners;
 
use App\Events\ChirpCreated;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Notifications\NewChirp;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
 
class SendChirpCreatedNotifications implements ShouldQueue
{
 ...
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
 
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     */
    public function handle(ChirpCreated $event): void
    {
        foreach (User::whereNot('id', $event->chirp->user_id)->cursor() as $user) {
            $user->notify(new NewChirp($event->chirp));
        }
    }
}

Or here.
app/Events/ChirpCreated.php
<?php
 
namespace App\Events;
 
use App\Models\Chirp;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
 
class ChirpCreated
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
 
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public function __construct(public Chirp $chirp)
    {
        //
    }
 ...
    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [
            new PrivateChannel('channel-name'),
        ];
    }
 
}

I appreciate if you could help me.
Add more information(Apr 16, 2024)
"is not dispatched" means no dispatch message is issued in the log. No matter how many chirp is issued, logfile(storage/logs/laravel.log) hasn't been appended. That means event and listener won't work.

Check your .env file.
MAIL_MAILER=log

In Laravel 11, the log driver is the default, so no emails are actually sent.
Look at the log files in storage/logs/.

Thank you so much. I'll check it out later. But I have another question, it seems like no event listener is working. Should I need some preparation?

Try to register your event and listener by adding
    protected $listen = [
    ChirpCreated::class => [
        SendChirpCreatedNotifications::class,
    ],
];

at App\Providers\EventServiceProvider

Thanks. I'm sure I will check it later.
